# Sum subtract not work in all input fields

Tags: javascript

How i use this js for sum and subtract for all input field ,when i use this its work for only 1st field only any one help me out for this.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    //this calculates values automatically 
    sum();
    $("#num1, #num2").on("keydown keyup", function() {
        sum();
    });
});

function sum() {
    var num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
    var num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
 var result = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
 var result1 = parseInt(num2) - parseInt(num1);
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
          document.getElementById('sum').value = result;
    document.getElementById('subt').value = result1;
    }
}
```

Comment: which part of your code is not working?

Comment: @anup dwivedi please create a fiddle

Comment: First field as in `num1`? You might want to change your `sum` function to accept the parameters you want to subtract / add rather than finding the values inside the function.

Comment: Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/osxvkeqo/1/

Comment: my code is  working but problem is its apply in 1st row only its can't subtract in 2nd row I have multiple row for fees..where am wrong

Comment: its cant works in multiple rows only apply in 1st row

Answer (score 0):

this is working...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#t1,#t2").keyup(function(){
                var t1=parseInt($("#t1").val());
                var t2=parseInt($("#t2").val());
                var t3=t1+t2;
                var t4=t1-t2;
                $("#t3").val(t3);  
                $("#t4").val(t4);  
        });
    });
    </script>
    <input type="text" id="t1" value="0">
    <input type="text" id="t2" value="0">
    <input type="text" id="t3">
    <input type="text" id="t4">
```

Comment: my code is also working but problem is its apply in 1st row only its can't subtract in 2nd row where am wrong ??